# What spatial-temporal analysis technique should I use to find the spatial-temporal overlap of two point datasets?

Tags: gis, spatial, overlap, temporal

I have human popularity data from Safegraph, giving the number of visits per hour at commercial locations. I also have wildlife data, giving the locations of each animal for every hour. How could I find which places and hours of the day are most "popular" by both humans and wildlife?

I was thinking to use spatial-temporal DBSCAN or k-means separately on both datasets and somehow compare the overlap, but I'm not sure if this would be the right approach.